# custom link on standard page layout

Tags: custom-field, standard-objects, custom

I am very very new to salesforce, so if my question does not sound good to you than I would just request you to ignore.

I Need to show one custom link on Contact Standard Object which will link to Account parent record. I created a link like `"/00b28000000FJlw/e?{!Account.Id}"` and saved. But, when i am trying to add this on page using page layout, I found it is marked as Grey[Under Custom Links Module] and could not be placed anywhere on page. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: The lookup field on the Contact will have a link to the parent account anyways. But if you do need a custom link then add a screenshot of the issue so the folks here can better understand the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am correct you want to edit account. So considering you want to edit account then you can go with command link button.
Now in Content Source use on click javascript and put below javascript code to naviagate to edit page of account.

```
window.location.href='{!Account.Id }/e';
```

Command links can only be added to command links section of page layout. So drag your field to command link section then you would be able to add command link.

Below snapshots will help you to create command link and add it to page layout.
[image]

[image]